# decimal representation of reals

Tags: analysis

If the real numbers are given as infinite decimalexpansions (or in some other base) then some rational numbers have two decimal representations and you have to choose one.
I've seen somewhere that the set of these are dense in the real numbers. Is there an elementary proof of this?

Comment: Hint: one of those two representations is *finite* (btw, you don't *have* to choose one, both represent precisely the same real number). Now, for base $10$ for example, show that $\{ m / 10^n \mid m \in \mathbb{Z}, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thank you for this comment. I've been reading about Cantor and his mapping from the line to the square where he had to choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base $B\geq 2$:

(1).For any $r>0$ there exists $n_r\in \mathbb N$ with $B^{-n_r}<r.$ For $r$ has a representation in base $B$ with a non-zero value in the  $k^{th}$ place to the right of the "decimal" place for some $k>0.$ So let $n_r=k+1.$

(2). The set you refer to is $$S=\{\pm (c+dB^{-e})\}$$ over all non-negative integers $c,d,e$ such that (i) $c,d$ are not both $0,$ and (ii) $0\leq d<B^e.$

(3).  For any $x\in \mathbb R$ and any $r>0,$ let $c\leq |x|<1+c$ where $c\in \mathbb N\cup \{0\}.$

By (1), let $e\in \mathbb N$ with $B^{-e}<r.$ There is a unique  integer $d,$ with $0\leq d<B^e,$ such that $$c+dB^{-e}\leq |x|<c+(1+d)B^{-e}.$$  At least one member ( which we will call $y$) of $\{c+dB^{-e}, c+(1+d)B^{-e}\}$, is a member of $S.$  The numbers $\pm y$ are both in $S.$

If $x\geq 0$ then $|x-y|\leq B^{-e}<r.$

If $x<0$ then $|x-(-y)|\leq B^{-e}<r.$

Comment: Thank you for this very clear proof, I think I understand it as covering the case of x being an integer etc. I'm sorry I cannot upvote it due to my reputation.

Comment: I tried to work within the def'n of  $\mathbb R$ as the set of decimal sequences. An important corollary of (1) is that there is no positive real which is smaller than any positive rational, which implies there is a  rational between any 2 reals. It is possible to extend $\mathbb R$ to an arithmetic with "infinitesimals" but that is another topic.